# Android: CDATA in XML

Tags: android, xml

I created my app a `XML parser`. But I can not see the data in the XML when it contains **´** or **ñ**. How I can fix it? thanks

**XML**

```
<item>

<color><![CDATA[<p>á é í ó ú ñ</p>]]></color>

</item>
```

**EDIT:**

The content of XML not shows in Windows

Comment: Show your code. Did you create your own XML parser? There is no need for that, Android comes with a good parser.

Comment: I create my XML in Windows and it not shows the contents to open it. The problem is not Android.

Comment: So u create this XML in Android.. and try to open it in Windows... Confuzd!!!

Comment: My XML is created en Windows and uploaded to server

Comment: where is Android involved here... I see ur tags say "Android"